# Sanitize time duration data from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm parsing a dataset in *.csv format using Python 2.7.14 and Pandas. I'm interested in performing time duration statistical analysis based on grouping by some attribute. Problem is, whenever I try to group and apply median, I get error

```
TypeError: invalid literal for float(): 00:00:11
```

Duration is given as a string, format is HH:MM:SS. I tried to convert to timedelta or datetime, but everytime the error shows up.
I was able to find the first row throwing the error in the csv file, modify the duration value and observed that the error thrown updates accordingly (i.e. 00:00:11 becomes whatever I wrote). Error was several thousands lines into the source csv. Removing the line made the error move to another line, not the one right below the one removed.

I'm stuck: I cannot perform automated analysis and cannot find a workaround to identify ill-type lines and remove them.

I've made some research and found out that is a common thread, but every solution provided was specific to a single problem and none fit my needs.

Here is the latest code I come up to:

import pandas
import numpy

```
df = pandas.read_csv('log.csv',sep=",", quotechar="\"", names=["attrA","attrB","attrC","attrD","attrE","attrF","attrG","skip1","attrH","attrI","attrJ","attrL","attrM","attrN","attrO","attrP","attrQ","Duration","User","Host"], encoding="utf-8-sig")
group_host = df.groupby('Host')
for host, value in group_host['Duration']:
    print((host, value.median()))
```

Here is an example of the dataset (sensible data was obscured):

```
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:03:10","userA","hostA"
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:00:34","userA","hostB"
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:00:54","userA","hostA"
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:02:30","userA","hostB"
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:03:04","userA","hostA"
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:00:44","userA","hostA"
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:01:09","userA","hostB"
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:00:42","userA","hostA"
"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","00:00:11","userA","hostB"
```

1) how can I sanitize the input data?
  1a) I tried adding `df.dropna(subset=['Duration'])` and/or `pandas.to_timedelta(df.Duration,errors='coerce')` without any luck.
2) alternatively, how can I identify by hand the lines and remove them?

Note: the dataset was aggregated from several different files using an automated script. Ill-lines are not at the beginning nor at the end of the files.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong when you convert them to a `timedelta`? I don't seem to have any issue with the sample you provided.

Comment: Nothing goes wrong during conversion. At run time, i get the error using the provided mwe on the dataset. I was sure I copied one of the bad lines that throw the error, tomorrow back in the office I will add a new sample to be sure.

Comment: @ALollz, the last line of the sample data is for sure giving me troubles